# squidguard issue configuring.getting same error over and over again

Tags: squid

Well, I installed Squid3 the other day and then installed Quintolabs, but I discovered this program `squidguard` that looks much easier to work with and configure and it looks like it would serve as a more adequate web filter for my needs.

I installed squidguard seemingly without a problem and I am following [this tutorial](http://www.danscourses.com/Linux-Fundamentals/install-a-configure-squidguard-in-ubuntu.html).  I am at the part when I just finished installing the blacklist and now I am trying to do a test run of squidguard with output to `stderr` using the command `squidGuard -d` (I am a total newbie with linux and am not that familiar with any commands or the file system or anything being used to Windows for so long).  This is what shows in the terminal which includes the error:

```
administrator@LinuxWebFilter:~$ squidGuard -d
squidGuard: error while loading shared libraries: libdb-4.8.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have no idea what to do or how to fix this.  Can someone please help with this?

Comment: any idea moon.musick?? @moon.musick

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get install libdb4.8`. Or perhaps `db4.8-util` if `libdb4.8` is obsolete.

In general, you might try looking up a file with `apt-file search FILENAME`.

```
$ apt-file search libdb-4.8.so
libdb4.8: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdb-4.8.so
```

It's the result in my system, in yours it may be different.

Comment: root@hassaan-OptiPlex-GX620:/usr/lib# apt-file search libdb-4.8.so
db4.8-util: /usr/lib/libdb-4.8.so
 it says its in this directory but i cant find it there

Comment: `apt-file` searches the database of both installed and not installed packages. `apt-get install` installs a package. Apparently your system lacks the file, which is provided by `libdb4.8` package. Try installing the package with `apt-get install`, as in the answer, and check if `squidguard` works then.

Comment: root@hassaan-OptiPlex-GX620:/# apt-get install libdb4.8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libdb4.8 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  db4.8-util

E: Package 'libdb4.8' has no installation candidate
root@hassaan-OptiPlex-GX620:/#

Comment: @hassaan ok, try then `db4.8-util` if it supersedes the `libdb4.8` package. Actually you already got the package name (and I overlooked it) in the output of `apt-file search` in your first comment.

Comment: sir if you dont mind do you use skpye? it'll be a great place to get the guidance from you..i can well understand everything there ..its a request..

Comment: now im executing this command "apt-get install db4.8-util"

Comment: @hassaan how did that go then?

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/profile`

and add

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/<yourusername>/db4.8.30/build_unix//.libs:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: This answer should be expanded to explain why this resolves the issue, and what this action does.